# Overlapped elements with onclick event

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, overlap, overlapping

Here is the deal:

The dark square has a `onclick` event attached
The red square, which overlaps the dark square, also have its own `onclick` event.

[image]

When I click the red square, I'd like only the red square's `onclick` event to be fired.
When I click the dark square, I'd like only the dark square's `onclick` event to be fired.

Currently, both are fired, and this is a problem for me.

How can I achieve my goal?

Some piece of code:

```
$('#dark-square').loadData({
    //load some HTML template with red square element inside
    //Red square looks like :
    //<div id="red-square" onclick="myFunction()">Some plain text</div>
}).click(function() {
    //what to do when dark-square only is clicked
})
```

```
#red-square {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 9px !important;
    right: 16px !important;
    z-index: 1000 !important; //I tried that to force the element to be on the top, but no result on onclick
}

//#dark-square is just a div with width / height
```

**TIP** : For simplicity, I'd like to keep the Javascript syntax to add my `onclick` event on dark square, and inline syntax on red square.

Comment: You need to prevent the event from bubbling up: https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that inline with `stopPropagation`.

```
<div onclick="alert('Red Square Clicked'); event.stopPropagation();">I am the red square</div>
```

Comment: Ok it was so easy I forget to use the `event.stopPropagation()`... It works well, thanks !